# How $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k+\frac{f^{(n)}(c_x)}{n!}(x-a)^n$ if $x<a$ using Taylor-Lagrange.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x>a$. I have Taylor-Lagrange formula that says that if 
 $f\in \mathcal C^{n}([a,x])$, then there is $c_x\in]a,x[$ such that 
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k+\frac{f^{(n)}(c_x)}{n!}(x-a)^n.$$

So, if $x<a$, we have that 
$$f(a)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(x)}{k!}(a-x)^k+\frac{f^{(n)}(c_x)}{n!}(a-x)^n,$$
don't we ? But I would like to get 
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k+\frac{f^{(n)}(c_x)}{n!}(x-a)^n$$
if $x<a$, how can I do ?

Comment: The first formula holds in all cases, as long as you think of the interval $[a,x]$ as a line segment rather than an ordered pair. In particular, this means that if $a<x$, then $c_x \in (a,x)$ and if $a>x$, then $c_x \in (a,x)$.

Comment: Elaborating slightly on copper.hat, the c_x term comes from the mean value theorem which enforces such an interval. By choosing the opposite interval you'll get a corresponding $c_x$.

Comment: Could you develop please ? My formula is only for $x>a$. how can I get the formula for $x<a$ ? i.e. the existence of a $d_x\in (x,a)$ s.t. $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k+\frac{f^{(n)}(d_x)}{n!}(x-a)^n.$ Thank you.

Comment: @Rick: Again, it involves the steps in deriving the formula. Do you have such a derivation at hand?

Comment: @AlexR: No I don't. So I can suppose that it also work on $(x,0)$ ? It's crazy that in all my research on the internet, I only find the formula like $f(b)=f(a)+f'(a)(b-a)+...$ on $[a,b]$, but never $f(b)=f(a)+f'(a)(b-a)+...$ on $[b,a]$, why ?

Comment: What is preventing you from defining $g(x)=f(-x)$. Wouldn't that solve your problem?